# QT Framework set encoding from CMD

Tags: qt, encoding, utf-8

How do I set the UTF-8 encoding for reading string. example

// outData = "абцд" -> Cyrillic alphabet

QMessageBox::information(this,"title",outData,"ok");

```
 void MainWindow::read() {
       myProcess = new QProcess();
       myProcess->start(QDir::currentPath() + "program.exe args args");
       connect(myProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readOutput()));
    }

    void MainWindow::readOutput() {
       QString outData = myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
    }
```

Comment: `readAllStandardOutput()` returns a `QByteArray`. You can pass that to [`QString::fromUtf8()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8-1) to get a `QString` out of your UTF-8 data.

Comment: @Mike not work show me 
hieroglyphics     outData from cmd -> абцд
     `QByteArray outData = myProcess->readAllStandardOutput(); 
QMessageBox::information(this,"title",QString::fromUtf8(outData),"ok");`

Comment: I found the solution:

    QByteArray outData = myProcess->readAllStandardOutput(); 
    QString::fromLocal8Bit(outData);  thanks